How do I get the built-in VNC server to work in 24.04.1?
I swear, every time I upgrade to a new LTS version VNC breaks. I have a headless Ubuntu box running 24.04.1. I just want to be able to VNC into it and see the same desktop I'd see if I plugged a monitor into it. I have a dummy HDMI adapter plugged into the back. It seems that the default vino server (if that's what Ubuntu still uses) is not running.
david@zoidberg:~$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 5900
[sudo] password for david:
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     25900    1642/dbus-daemon     /run/user/1000/bus

It looks like vino isn't installed anymore by default - is that correct?
Is there a way to enable VNC via the command line? Why does this always break?
